# Let $A$ a dense subset of $B$. Can $A$ have no limit points in $B$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis

Let $A$ a dense subset of $B$. Can $A$ have no limit points in $B$? I think the answer is no but I didn't find it anywhere.

I have the circle $|z| = m < 1$ and a set A of points which is dense in that circle. I want to prove that the set A have a limit point in unit disk $\mathbb{D}$

Comment: If $A=B$ and $B$ is a discrete space then $A$ has no limit points in $B.$

Comment: It's a technicality, but an isolated point of a set is not considered to be a limit point. So with $A = B = \{x\}$, $A$ is dense in $B$ but has no limit points in $B$. Your set $\Bbb{D}$ has no isolated points, so you don't need to worry about this.

Comment: And for my circle how can I show that has a limit point in $\mathbb{D}$?

Comment: Every point on the fixed circle is a limit point for $A$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what you are describing is an open ball, not a circle (circle would be the points where $|z| = 1$).

More to the point of the question, the closure of a set $A$ is equal to $A \cup A'$, where $A'$ is the set of all limit points of $A$. This is a basic theorem in topology with an incredibly simple proof: if $x \in A$, it's obviously in the closure of $A$, otherwise, every neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $A$, meaning every deleted neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $A$, meaning $x \in A'$.

So, the question is: if $B = A \cup A'$, is there a point in $A'$ that is in $B$? Well, if $A'$ is non-empty, yes. $A'$ is empty if and only if $B = A$ and it has the discrete topology, which is clearly not the case in your example.

Comment: I doubt whether the OP will understand your answer. I can guess what you mean by "deleted neighbourhood" and can figure out what "it" refers to in "it has the discrete topology", but I doubt whether the OP will.